# Can't manage state arrays

Tags: react-native, axios, state

i want to get JSON data from API, but i don't know the size of this data.
the data is like a history "consists of name and picture".
there is an error with the variables name and avatar.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MenuButton from '../components/MenuButton';
import User from '../components/User';
import API from '../Utils/API';

export default class SettingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      name: [],
      avatar:[]
    };
  }
  render() {
    var userCard=[];
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      userCard.push(
        <View>
        <User name={this.state.name[i]} avatar={this.state.avatar[i]}/>
      </View>
        )}

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <MenuButton navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
        {userCard}
      </View>
    );
  }

async componentDidMount() {
// Load async data.
  let userData = await API.get('/', {
      params: {
        results: 1,
        inc: 'name,avatar'
      }
    }); 

    // Parse the results for ease of use.
    for(let i=0; i<userData.length; i++){
      const Data = userData.data[i];
      const names = Data.name;
      const base64Icon=Data.image;
      const base64Icons=base64Icon.slice(2,-1);
      const avatar = 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+base64Icons;
          this.setState(state=>{
         const name=state.name.push(names);
        return{
          name,
          avatar,
        }
      });
    }
  }
  }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
   }
 });
```

When i try to run the app a warning appears:
warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the render function, where you do the for loop, add a key prop in every view:

```
 for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
      userCard.push(
        <View key={i}>
        <User name={this.state.name[i]} avatar={this.state.avatar[i]}/>
      </View>
        )}
```

You need to put inside the key a unique value. If you have a id for that user card, use that one instead of `i`

Comment: Invariant violation: invariant violation: Text string must be rendered within a <Text> component.
This errors appears because name is not array of strings, do you know why is that ?

Comment: Did my solution give you that error? can i see the code?

Comment: This is the code of the component User 

class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { name, avatar} = this.props;

    const userDetails = (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image style={styles.img} source={{uri: avatar}}/>
          <Text>Name: {name} </Text>
        </View>
    );
    return (
      <Card>
      {userDetails}
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

Comment: Hey, i see you created another question with this issue, if I helped you solving your issue, please accept my answer

Comment: Your answer already helped me on the first problem. Thank you so much.